# Where does python send files without a directory path?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Windows 10

Anyway I used os.rename and forgot to add a directory path to the beginning. Where did my files end up?

Comment: in your current working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file could be sent to the current working directory. To find the current working directory, use

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

To find out where the file you are executing is located, use

```
import os 
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```